# How can I get the data I want from an url address

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, vuejs2

I had a VUE page that jump from Native side, in order to get the api params I want, Native side passing the data as a url form like

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hon.smarthome/files/w…tail_base/index.html?iotId=xdN3ywsqvJu2tHgY4mOf000000&platform=1#/main
```

The `1` and `xdN3ywsqvJu2tHgY4mOf000000` is the data I want
So I use split to get those data

```
var url = window.location.href; 
var cutNumberSign = url.split('#')[0];
var iotIdPlusPlatform = cutNumberSign.split('?')[1];
var cutIotId = iotIdPlusPlatform.split('iotId=')[1];
var platfrom = cutIotId.split('platform=')[1];
var iotId = cutIotId.split('&')[0];
this.iotId = iotId;
this.platform = platfrom;
```

It works totally fine from `Android` side
However from `iOS` I got, the data order was not the same, it was like

```
index.html?platform=1&iotId=xdN3ywsqvJu2tHgY4mOf000000#/main
```

so the split will not work,
How can I get those data no matter the order is?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new `URL` object and get the `searchParams`.

```js
var params = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;

var platform = params.get('platform')
var iotId = params.get('iotId')
```

```js
console.log(platform) // 1
console.log(iotId)    // xdN3ywsqvJu2tHgY4mOf000000
```